# Позиционирование перевернутых блоков

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, flexbox

Всем привет. Есть макет:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Реализовывается методом колонок. Левая колонка, средняя, правая колонка. Фиксированная высота блоков. Весь хедер - 160 px. Позиционирование на флексах везде отрегулировано на середину. Левая колонка - две строки, которые не удается правильно спозиционировать. Получается следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код HTML:

```
    <header>
    <div class="container">
        
        <div class="left_column">
            <div class="logo logo_up">ative</div>
            <div class="logo logo_down">cre</div>
        </div>

        <div class="center_column">
            <div class="title">
                Web Studio
            </div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="item">прайс-лист</div>
                <div class="item">studio cms</div>
                <div class="item">кейсы</div>
                <div class="item">отзывы</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right_column">
            <div class="blue"> </div>
            <div class="light_blue"> </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
    .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.center_column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.left_column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;

}

.title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    height: 96px;

    background-color: #5FB4D9;

    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 59px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 22px;

    height: 64px;

    background-color: #479DC2;
}

.item {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 29px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.logo_up {
    background-color: #5FB4D9;

    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #479DC2;
    height: 96px;
}

.logo_down {
    background-color: #479DC2;

    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #5FB4D9;
    height: 64px;
}

.logo {
    margin-top: 20px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}

.right_column {
    width: 50px;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #479DC2;
    height: 96px;

}

.light_blue {
    background-color: #5FB4D9;
    height: 64px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я бы посоветовал Вам посмотреть в сторону css-свойства вертикального написания текста: `writing-mode: vertical-rl;`. Идея в том, чтобы Вы непосредственно Ваш текст "Creative" обернули в какой-нибудь тэг `span` и ему задали это свойство.

А самому блоку `logo` укажите какую-нибудь ширину, чтобы он не схлопнулся при вертикальном тексте. Моё решение выглядит так:

```css
 .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.center_column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.left_column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    height: 96px;

    background-color: #5FB4D9;

    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 59px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 22px;

    height: 64px;

    background-color: #479DC2;
}

.item {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 29px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    color: #FFFFFF;
}

.logo_up {
    background-color: #5FB4D9;

    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #479DC2;
    height: 96px;
    border-right: 2px solid #479DC2;
}

.logo_down {
    background-color: #479DC2;

    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #5FB4D9;
    height: 64px;
    border-right: 2px solid #5FB4D9;
}

.logo {
    width: 30px;
}

.logo span {
      writing-mode: vertical-rl;
      transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.right_column {
    width: 50px;
}

.blue {
    background-color: #479DC2;
    height: 96px;

}

.light_blue {
    background-color: #5FB4D9;
    height: 64px;
}
```

```html
<header>
    <div class="container">
        
        <div class="left_column">
            <div class="logo logo_up"><span>ative</span></div>
            <div class="logo logo_down"><span>cre</span></div>
        </div>

        <div class="center_column">
            <div class="title">
                Web Studio
            </div>
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="item">прайс-лист</div>
                <div class="item">studio cms</div>
                <div class="item">кейсы</div>
                <div class="item">отзывы</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="right_column">
            <div class="blue"> </div>
            <div class="light_blue"> </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</header>
```

**P.S.** И на будущее, подобные элементы страницы, имеющие столбцы и строки, я бы лично верстал с помощью `grid`

Comment: Благодарю, повторил код, чуть подкорректировал под макет, все отлично встало. Да, надо гриды подучить для таких случаев)

Answer (score 0):

Вот такой вот код получился у меня.
Это совсем неправильно но мне лень делать по-другому))

```css
  .container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .center_column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }

  .left_column {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    height: 96px;

    background-color: #5FB4D9;

    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 800;
    font-size: 50px;
    line-height: 59px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }

  .navbar {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 22px;
    height: 64px;

    background-color: #479DC2;
  }

  .item {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: 29px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

    color: #FFFFFF;
  }

  .logo_up {
    background-color: #5FB4D9;
    color: #479DC2;
    height: 96px;
  }

  .logo {
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: 23px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: flex;
  }

  .logo p {
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }

  .logo_down {
    background-color: #479DC2;
    color: #5FB4D9;
    height: 64px;
  }



  .right_column {
    width: 50px;
  }

  .blue {
    background-color: #479DC2;
    height: 96px;

  }

  .light_blue {
    background-color: #5FB4D9;
    height: 64px;
  }
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="container">

    <div class="left_column">
      <div class="logo logo_up"><p>ative</p></div>
      <div class="logo logo_down"><p>cre</p></div>
    </div>

    <div class="center_column">
      <div class="title">
        Web Studio
      </div>
      <div class="navbar">
        <div class="item">прайс-лист</div>
        <div class="item">studio cms</div>
        <div class="item">кейсы</div>
        <div class="item">отзывы</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="right_column">
      <div class="blue"> </div>
      <div class="light_blue"> </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Не в упрек Вам, ни в коем случае, но скорее из чистого любопытства: если Вам лень и к тому же Вы и сами понимаете, что это совсем неправильно, то зачем же тогда делать?))

Comment: @Stark сам не знаю)